# Android - Geofence disappearing when app is killed

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

At the risk of being marked as duplicate, I ask this question once more. I've tried every proposed solution here in stackoverflow (except using a third party library because I want to use `GoogleAPIClient` instead) and still, I cannot make it work. I used `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver`; geofences still keep disappearing after I close the app. If it's in foreground or background, it works perfectly but completely killing the app also completely kills the geofences.

I've only tested it in Nougat and Marshmallow. Does the new Doze function of Android affect it? My GPS is always on, my device doesn't restart, although I've turned off my wifi/data because I want the geofencing to depend purely on the GPS. Oh, and I'm using a fake gps app to test it.

Below are the relevant parts of my code:

Home.java

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (db.isEmpty()) {
        getData(); //get geofences from the server. at this point, the wifi is still on
    } else {
        startGeofencing();
    }


}

 private void startGeofencing(){
    //Set up geofence
    GeofencingMethods gM = new GeofencingMethods(getApplicationContext(), prefs);
    RealmResults<ServerGeofence> geofenceList = realm.where(ServerGeofence.class).findAll();
    for (ServerGeofence g : geofenceList) {
        Geofence geofence = gM.createGeofence(g.getGeof_name(), g.getGeof_lat(), g.getGeof_long(), g.getGeof_rad()*1000);
        gM.addToGeofencingRequest(geofence);
    }

    //Build googleApiClient and connect to service
    gM.buildGoogleApiClient();
}
```

GeofencingMethods.java

```
public class GeofencingMethods {
private GeofencingRequest.Builder geofencingRequestBuilder;
private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
private Context c;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

public GeofencingMethods(Context c, SharedPreferences prefs) {
    this.c = c;
    this.prefs = prefs;
    geofencingRequestBuilder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
}

public Geofence createGeofence(String name, double lat, double lng, float radius) {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(name)
            .setCircularRegion(lat, lng, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setLoiteringDelay(Constants.LOITERING_DELAY) //10 minutes dwelling
            .build();
}

public void addToGeofencingRequest(Geofence g) {
           prefs.edit().putInt(Constants.GEOFENCE_NUM, prefs.getInt(Constants.GEOFENCE_NUM, 0)+1).commit();
    geofencingRequestBuilder.addGeofence(g);
}

public PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {
    if (geofencePendingIntent != null) return geofencePendingIntent;

 //   Intent intent = new Intent(c, GeofenceTriggeredService.class);
 //   geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(c, Constants.PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_GEOFENCE_RECEIVED);
    geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, Constants.PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return geofencePendingIntent;
}

public void addToGeofencingApi(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }

    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            googleApiClient, geofencingRequestBuilder.build(), createPendingIntent())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                c,
                                "Geofences added",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();

                    } else if (status.getStatusCode() == 1000) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                c,
                                "Please turn on Google Location services in Settings. Switch to \"High Accuracy\" mode",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();


                        prefs.edit().putInt(Constants.GEOFENCE_NUM, 0).commit();
                    }


                }
            });
}
//Building googleAPI client
public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(c)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        System.out.println("GOOGLE API CLIENT CONNECTED");
                        addToGeofencingApi();
                        //Go to service when triggered

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        if(googleApiClient!=null){
                            googleApiClient.connect();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient. Please restart application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    }
    if(!googleApiClient.isConnected() && !googleApiClient.isConnecting()){
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

GeofenceReceiver.java

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Context c;
private SharedPreferences prefs;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.c = context;
    prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));

        }
    }

    if ("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (realm.where(ServerGeofence.class).count() <= 0) {
                getData();
            } else {
                startGeofencing();
            }
        } else {
            // go to settings and do it!!
        }
    }

    if(Constants.ACTION_GEOFENCE_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence Spotted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new NotificationMaker(context).geofenceEvent(intent);
    }
}
```

NotificationMaker.java

```
public class NotificationMaker {
private Context c;
private int s;

public NotificationMaker(Context c){
    this.c = c;
}

public void geofenceEvent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "ERROR: " + getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
            || geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences);

        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);

    }
}

private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    String status = null;
    s = 0;
    if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
        status = "Entering ";
        s = 0;
    } else if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
        status = "Dwelling ";
        s = 1;
    } else if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        status = "Exiting ";
        s = 2;
    }

    //log event

    return status + TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
}

private String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "GeoFence not available";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "Too many GeoFences";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "Too many pending intents";
        default:
            return "Unknown error.";
    }
}

private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {

    System.out.println("Creating notification");
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(com.google.android.gms.R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText("Geofence Spotted")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    return notificationBuilder.build();


}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    System.out.println("Sending notification");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(c, Home.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(c);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Home.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));
}
```

}

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Home"/>


    <service android:name="com.example.GeofenceTriggeredService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.GeofenceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.location.MODE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.example.ACTION_GEOFENCE_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: When you mean completely killing the app, do you mean going into the settings and hitting "Force Stop"?

Comment: I meant just exiting the app -- swiping it away from the list of opened apps

Comment: Move all the logic to build and monitor your geofences from your Activity to a Service. Since you have nothing else running when you swipe your activity from the list, you essentially kill the app. Make sure your service `onStartCommand` returns `START_STICKY`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon boot and starting the app I would start an IntentService that then registers a Geofence:

```
public class RegisterGeoIntentService extends IntentService {
...
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.xyz.app.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
```

And then in the registered Intent:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
...

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if(geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeoErrorMessages.getErrorString(context, geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
...
```